# Selection only on visible part of a shape?

Tags: swing, jgraphx

I would like to have the JGraphX editor to be able to select a shape only if the user click on a visible part of the shape instead of the full bounding box of a shape. For instance, if you insert a Triangle in a graph, I want to be able to select it only by clicking inside the triangle.

This would also be usefull after a rotation because the "bounding box" can be totally different than the visible shape once rotated.

Both things are working really well in draw.io, so I just would like to know where to look at in the Javascript to be able to do it in the Java Swing version.

Thank you.

Comment: No doubt, you would love to walk through [playing with shapes](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/). Hope it helps :-)